# Divide Legal page into three parts in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am working on a `VB.NET` project. In that we have `Visual Studio 2012`, `.NET Framework 4.5.1` and `Crystal Reports 13.0.13.1597`

I need to print a receipt and as per requirement, I need to fit 3 receipts on one single `Legal` Size page. Considering the margins, I managed to design a receipt which fits in required length.

Please refer image for receipt layout and printing page preferences. [Receipt Image with Layout and Properties](http://imgur.com/D6X1A9v)

I tried to print the out very different setting, but I am not getting print at the upper side of the `Legal` page.

I tried to Create Custom Printing form (Dimensions referred in image) in Printer Properties, selected input paper as `Legal` and output paper as `Custom Paper Size` but that did not worked too.

All I am getting is print at the center of the page.

Comment: how are you getting this in preview?

Comment: As i have created Custom sized page in .NET, i am seeing full page preview.